# cURL vs RestSharp vs Rest.net behaving differently with Tumblr

Tags: c#, curl, tumblr, restsharp

I am trying to get data from the Tumblr API and get different results since they introduced the GDPR/Advertisers page in front. The page is supposed to appear once and set a cookie.

With cUrl:

```
curl -i -v -X GET "https://nochillmemes.tumblr.com/api/read/json?type=photo&num=50&start=1"
```

I get proper results.

With Rest.Net:

```
var Client = new RestClient("https://nochillmemes.tumblr.com");
var Request = new RestRequest("/api/read/json?filter=text&type=photo&num=50&start=1", Http.Method.GET);
var R = Client.Execute(Request);
```

returns the GDPR page, but:

```
var Client = new RestClient("https://nochillmemes.tumblr.com");
var Request = new RestRequest("/api/read/json?filter=text&type=photo&num=50&start=1", Http.Method.GET);
Request.AddHeader("user-agent", "curl/7.54.0");
var R = Client.Execute(Request);
```

returns the proper data! so tumblr returns different results based on the user agent.

With RestSharp:

```
var Client = new RestClient("https://nochillmemes.tumblr.com");
var Request = new RestRequest("/api/read/json?filter=text&type=photo&num=50&start=1", Method.GET);
var R = Client.Execute(Request);
```

returns the GDPR page, and:

```
var Client = new RestClient("https://nochillmemes.tumblr.com");
var Request = new RestRequest("/api/read/json?filter=text&type=photo&num=50&start=1", Method.GET);
Request.AddHeader("user-agent", "curl/7.54.0");
var R = Client.Execute(Request);
```

still returns the GDPR page...

So, in summary:

- cURL gives me the API results
- Rest.Net gives me the API results only if it pretends to be cURL
- Restsharp always gives me the GDPR page

What could be the reason for this?

I'm trying to understand what is happening because I don't want to rely on something that works without knowing why :)

Comment: Have you used Wire Shark to compare the difference between the requests being made by the tools? Is there a particular reason you are setting the useragent that way rather than setting `UserAgent` directly? https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/787

Comment: It works, so the issue was how I was setting the header!  I think this part is counter intuitive in RestSharp's API; thanks a lot for the help, you have saved me a lot of time.

Comment: Great! I've tried a lot to get it working and now fixed it by only set User Agent to a curl one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is how you are setting the user agent header in `RestSharp`.

As per [this github issue](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/787), rather than:

```
Request.AddHeader("user-agent", "curl/7.54.0");
```

you should use:

```
Client.UserAgent = "curl/7.54.0";
```